# Quais as vantagens e desvantagens de erros encapsulados tipos como "Result"?

Tags: exceção, estilo-de-codificação, rust, tipos-algébricos

Estou aprendendo Rust e uma das coisas que me deixou curioso é a ausência de exceções.

Ao contrário de linguagens como C#, Java, JavaScript etc, que possuem exceções, em Rust isso não existe. Se uma função pode falhar e o erro deve ser tratado (o que chamam de *recoverable error*), há de se retornar um valor cujo tipo se chama [`Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html) (é uma enumeração, mas isso não vem ao caso).

Parece que a ausência de exceções tem se tornado moda. Rust e Go são duas linguagens relativamente novas que não possuem essa ideia tão fundamentada na linguagem.

- Quais as vantagens e desvantagens de tipos como o `Result`?
- Em linguagens como Rust, que obrigam o `Result` para *recoverable errors* e possuem um sistema como `panic!` (em tese não tratáveis) para *unrecoverable errors*, a ausência de exceções pode ser um empecilho?
- Em linguagens com exceções, o chamador de uma função pode optar por não tratar o erro. Mas com `Result` isso não me parece possível implicitamente. O que fazer nesses casos? Sou obrigado a tratar todo erro possível?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Exceções são difíceis de implementar em linguagens tipo C++ e Rust, que não têm "coletor de lixo" e compilam para binário.**

Um programa que use exceções fica um pouco mais lento, e principalmente o binário fica muito maior, pois todos os possíveis caminhos de execução adicionais, que passam a existir pela possibilidade da exceção, tem de ser tratados.

(Isto era um problema maior em 2001, já não é tão relevante porque os compiladores C++ evoluíram muito, e C++ é mais rapido que Go com exceções e tudo.)

**Exceções deveriam ser usadas para tratar "situações excepcionais" mas a definição de "excepcional" é ambígua e varia muito conforme o contexto**.

Falha ao abrir um arquivo pode ou não ser algo excepcional, depende do que o programa faz.

Falha ao abrir uma conexão de rede é excepcional? Na minha opinião, não é, porque a rede pode e vai falhar de diversas formas o tempo todo.

Converter uma string para inteiro deve levantar uma exceção? Depende do contexto. Se for durante o parsing de um documento preenchido por um humano, não dá pra dizer que a ocorrência de um erro é excepcional...

Ao parsear um JSON, deve ser levantada uma exceção em caso de JSON inválido? Acho que não, pois faz parte do trabalho normal de um parser verificar se um documento é válido.

**Como você mesmo disse, exceções podem ou não ser tratadas, e aí começam a aparecer os débitos técnicos e os bugs,** principalmente quando a "exceção" é algo perfeitamente esperado, como por exemplo uma falha na conexão via rede, situação que o código jamais poderia deixar de tratar.

Nessa toada, estruturas no estilo "Result" encorajam o desenvolvimento mais robusto, e com o tratamento de erro ocorrendo o mais perto possível da sua origem.

Em linguagens interpretadas, tipo Javascript e Python, exceções são uma necessidade porque podem ocorrer erros de runtime que são bugs mesmo, tipo variável com nome errado, tipo errado, etc. Imagine um servidor REST: é útil que uma exceção levantada num endpoint por um bug no código seja "capturada", em vez de deixá-la derrubar o servidor inteiro (a falha em um endpoint não necessariamente impede que os demais continuem sendo usados).

Mas em linguagens estáticas esse tipo de erro não pode ocorrer em runtime. Os problemas que podem ocorrer em runtime que se pode imaginar, têm de ser tratados explicitamente.